# Mixing hosting providers

Tags: amazon-aws, cloud-hosting, react-js, firebase, netlify

Is there any benefit from using all the services from 1 hosting provider (like Firebase) vs. mixing and matching?

For example,:

**Option 1:** I host my React app on Netlify, but use Firebase for authentication and AWS for file storage.

**Option 2** Host, auth and storage on Netlify only

It almost seems like there is an optimal mix of providers in terms of cost, but is there an obvious downside?

Comment: The downside is if you don't understand DNS.  It makes things more complex, so if you aren't on top of exactly what it is you are doing, where you are doing it and why you are doing it, things are likely to end in tears and heartache.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Among other things to consider -

- Increased complexity and reduced security - more providers = more attack surface and more difficulties securing communication between providers.
- Increased latencies compared to multiple services in same data centre.  This may not matter depending on how far apart the DC's are and the nature of your traffic, but could be significant.
- Possible hidden costs - many providers charge per gig for some services - and are more likely to charge when data is leaving their platform.
- More billing complexity, and greater likelyhood that future audits miss some resources which are redundant.
- If there is a fault that seems to be related to a provider, its a lot easier for a provider to duck and dive if you have some services with other providers.

There are, of-course, upsides in terms of redundancy, not putting your eggs in one basket, cost etc.